# PSQL/SQL constraint to insert or delete

Tags: sql, insert, constraints, psql

I have these tables:

```
user
id

permission
id
user_id

old_permission
user_id
value
```

Values:

```
user
id
1
2
3

permission
id    user_id
1     1     
2     2


old_permission
user_id    value
1          f
2          f
3          t
```

As the table names suggest, I am migrating from a legacy permissions system. What I want to do is:

When old_permission.value is 't', i want any matching rows in permission for the user to be deleted. So if user 3 had an entry in the permission table, it would be deleted if its old_permission.value = 't'.

I also want to create a row in the permission table if the associated old_permission.value = 'f'

How can I create a constraint like this?

Comment: Hm, are you trying to do it as you go using a trigger, or just "once for all" and not use the old table? Also, "I also want to create a row in the permission table if the associated old_permission.value = 'f'", with what values for `id`? Just serial?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The tag `psql` suggests Postgres. However the `PSQL/SQL` seems to point more to Oracle (although it's called PL/SQL there and is only for writing stored procedures - it has nothing to do with constraint definitions).

Comment: Hi, the id for the permission table is just serial, not important. And i want it to first populate the permission table and then run every time the old_permission changes. I am using Postgres

Comment: @Ozzy - I wonder how is my answer is different then Tobsey's. The only diff. I see no query in my answer, which I think is not required. If you or others expect queries then care about adding tables and data at least. I do not have time to create tables and data, and this question is not simple...

Comment: @All - are those who ask questions completely incomp. to write simple queries even after you tell them what to do? Do we really have to write queries for them w/out knowing the structures and fully understand problems. This question is very good example of such things. Do users expect their code written for them when even description is vague? It is ridiculous!

Comment: @Art Those kind of questions can be spotted easily. Unless it's very clear what the OP wants, maybe just leave a comment and downvote it / vote for close until the question is answerable. I don't think this is one of those questions though. If you're willing to discuss further on this matter, I'm sure you'll get constructive feedback on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Xavi López - Thank you for suggestion. I totally agree with your comments. I never downvoted anyone but I think I should start doing this.

Comment: @Art, you might find these [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127899/169503) [posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1871/169503) interesting. If you think something deserves a downvote, you indeed ought to downvote it, leaving a comment if feeling like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a Stored Procedure that refreshes the Permission table based on the Old_Permission table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RefreshPermissions()
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE
        Permission
    WHERE
        EXISTS
        (SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            Old_Permission
        WHERE
            Permission.user_id = Old_Permission.user_id
        AND Old_Permission.Value = 't');

    INSERT INTO
        Permission (user_id)
    SELECT
        Old_Permission.user_id
    FROM
        Old_Permission
        LEFT JOIN Permission ON Old_Permission.user_id = Permission.user_id
    WHERE
        Old_Permission.Value = 'f'
    AND Permission.user_Id IS NULL;

END;
```

Then I would suggest using triggers on the Old_Permission table to modify the Permission table as needed. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    TR_Old_Permission
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON 
    Old_Permission
EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    RefreshPermissions();
```

Answer (score -1):

The PL/SQL is part of Oracle. And Constraints are part of SQL not PL/SQL. You cannot create constraints like this. You need to write some code, could be procedures and/or triggers that would delete and insert according to your logic. Basically, while migrating, and I do not know what exactly you are doing to migrate and how, you loop through records then delete and insert records according to your conditions/filters. It is hard to suggest anything more as I need more details to decide how and what to do exactly in your case.

Comment: I can only repeat my question for incompetent downvoters: how is my answer is different then Tobsey's?

Answer (score -1):

i am not able to understand the exact problem of yours,for that i thought of making u to understand the concept of the constraints in sql,including its defination and types.

Constraints are used to limit the type of data that can go into a table.

Constraints can be specified when a table is created (with the CREATE TABLE statement) or after the table is created (with the ALTER TABLE statement).

types of constraints:

•NOT NULL

•UNIQUE

•PRIMARY KEY

•FOREIGN KEY

•CHECK

•DEFAULT

Explanitation of the types of constraints with small examples for each:-

SQL NOT NULL Constraint

•The NOT NULL constraint enforces a column to NOT accept NULL values.

•The NOT NULL constraint enforces a field to always contain a value. This means that you 
cannot insert a new record, or update a record without adding a value to this field.

•The following SQL enforces the "P_Id" column and the "LastName" column to not accept NULL 
values:

•CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255)

)

SQL UNIQUE Constraint

The UNIQUE constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.

SQL UNIQUE Constraint on CREATE TABLE

The following SQL creates a UNIQUE constraint on the "P_Id" column when the "Persons" table

is created:

MySQL:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255),

UNIQUE (P_Id)

)

SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255)

)

To allow naming of a UNIQUE constraint, and for defining a UNIQUE constraint on multiple 
columns, use the following SQL syntax:

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255),

CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)

)

---

SQL UNIQUE Constraint on ALTER TABLE

To create a UNIQUE constraint on the "P_Id" column when the table is already created,
use the following SQL:

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

ALTER TABLE Persons

ADD UNIQUE (P_Id)

To allow naming of a UNIQUE constraint, and for defining a UNIQUE constraint on multiple 
columns, use the following SQL syntax:

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

ALTER TABLE Persons

ADD CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)

---

To DROP a UNIQUE Constraint

To drop a UNIQUE constraint, use the following SQL:

MySQL:

ALTER TABLE Persons

DROP INDEX uc_PersonID

SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

ALTER TABLE Persons

DROP CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID

---

SQL PRIMARY KEY Constraint

The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.

Primary keys must contain unique values.

A primary key column cannot contain NULL values.

Each table should have a primary key, and each table can have only ONE primary key.

---

SQL PRIMARY KEY Constraint on CREATE TABLE

The following SQL creates a PRIMARY KEY on the "P_Id" column when the "Persons" table is

created:

MySQL:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255),

PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)

)

SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255)

)

To allow naming of a PRIMARY KEY constraint, and for defining a PRIMARY KEY constraint on 
multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax:

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255),

CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id,LastName)

)

---

SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint on CREATE TABLE

The following SQL creates a FOREIGN KEY on the "P_Id" column when the "Orders" table is 
created:
MySQL:

CREATE TABLE Orders

(

O_Id int NOT NULL,

OrderNo int NOT NULL,

P_Id int,

PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),

FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)

)

SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

CREATE TABLE Orders

(

O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

OrderNo int NOT NULL,

P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)

)

To allow naming of a FOREIGN KEY constraint, and for defining a FOREIGN KEY constraint on 
multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax:
MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

CREATE TABLE Orders

(

O_Id int NOT NULL,

OrderNo int NOT NULL,

P_Id int,

PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),

CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)

REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)

)

---

SQL CHECK Constraint on CREATE TABLE

The following SQL creates a CHECK constraint on the "P_Id" column when the "Persons" table 
is created. The CHECK constraint specifies that the column "P_Id" must only include integers greater than 0.

MySQL:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255),

CHECK (P_Id>0)

)

---

SQL DEFAULT Constraint

The DEFAULT constraint is used to insert a default value into a column.

SQL DEFAULT Constraint on CREATE TABLE

The following SQL creates a DEFAULT constraint on the "City" column when the "Persons" 
table is created:

My SQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

CREATE TABLE Persons

(

P_Id int NOT NULL,

LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,

FirstName varchar(255),

Address varchar(255),

City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'

)

The DEFAULT constraint can also be used to insert system values, by using functions like 
GETDATE():

CREATE TABLE Orders

(

O_Id int NOT NULL,

OrderNo int NOT NULL,

P_Id int,

OrderDate date DEFAULT GETDATE()

)

above explination is in general format of using constraints,hope it may help you to overcome from your problem...........................

Comment: Please don't paste massive amounts of text from another source. If you feel the information is of use in answering the question, please add a link to it instead.